# Log file ruby testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, logging

I have this ruby script and I have a problem on the line 57..

please let me know where is the error

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

class CommonLog

# init method takes log filename, computes frequency counts
# for ips, urls & statuses
def initialize(log)
f = File.open(log)

@filename = log
@filesize = f.size
@ip_counts = Hash.new(0)
@url_counts = Hash.new(0)
@status_counts = Hash.new(0)

@total_records = 0

f.readlines.each do |line|
tokens = line.split(' ')

ip = tokens[0]
url = tokens[-4]
status = tokens[-2]

@ip_counts[ip] += 1
@url_counts[url] += 1
@status_counts[status] += 1
@total_records += 1
end

f.close
end

# displays filename and bytesize
def file_info
"Filename: #{@filename}, Bytes Transferred: #{@filesize}"
end

# draws ip histogram
def ip_hist
@ip_counts.each do |ip, freq|
puts "#{ip}: #{'*'*freq}"
end
puts file_info
end

# draws url histogram
def url_hist
@url_counts.each do |url,freq|
puts "#{url} #{'*'*freq}"
end
puts file_info
end

# draws list of statuses
def status_list
msg = ""
sorted_status_codes = @status_counts.keys.sort
sorted_status_codes do |code|
count = @status_counts[code]
pct = ((count.to_f/@total_records)*100).to_i
msg += "#{code}: #{percentage}%\n"
end
puts msg
puts file_info
end

end

def test
log = CommonLog.new('**TEST LOG FILE PATH**')
log.ip_histogram
log.url_histogram
log.status_codes
end

test()
```

Thank you for your help in advance.. your help would be much appreciated..
The log file is on the server, so I removed the path because you won't be able to reach it ..

Here are the message I get back after I run the file

```
    /1.rb:57:in `status_list': undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from ./1.rb:73:in `test'
      from ./1.rb:75:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you reformat the code with indentation?you have a syntax error at this line `sorted_status_codes do |code|`.

Comment: So what would be the correct code for this line?

Comment: `sorted_status_codes.each do |code|`, it's a loop

Comment: I did it and I got a different message now.

    ./1.rb:57:in `status_list': undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from ./1.rb:73:in `test'
    from ./1.rb:75:in `<main>'

Comment: Could you provide an example that work (shows the error). Your example defines `url_hist`but calls `url_histogramm`, the filename contains invalid characters, there is no check for existence of the log-file...

Comment: This is the error I get now.. ./1.rb:72:in `test': undefined local variable or method `log' for main:Object (NameError)
 from ./1.rb:76:in `<main>'


However, I changed the url_hist call to url_hist